# CSS Grid: auto height including 1 column with multiple content blocks?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I've checked out https://gridbyexample.com/example and have been trying myself to make this work, but can't get it to fit right. Check out the attached image for what I'm trying to do. Is there an easy CSS-Grid way to do this? [image]

What I have so far for CSS:

```
.main-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 15px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(225px, 1fr));
}

.box {
  height: min-content;
  
}

/* Targeting the 2nd content block in column 3 */
.box.d {
  grid-column: 3/6;
}
```

What I have so far for HTML:

```
<div class="main-container">
  <div class=-"box a">Content Here</div>
  <div class=-"box b">Content Here</div>
  <div class=-"box c">Content Here</div>
  <div class=-"box d">Content Here</div>
  <div class=-"box e">Content Here</div>
  <div class=-"box f">Content Here</div>
<div>
```

Comment: can you post what you have tried? thanks!

Comment: please add a chunk of code of what you have tried

Comment: @cornonthecob - added what I have so far

Comment: You also need to include your HTML. Without it, your CSS is doesn't tell us anything.

Comment: ok @disinfor added my html

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for:

[codepen](https://codepen.io/gvmohzibat/pen/XWKMmLM)

```css
.main-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 15px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(225px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: 2fr 2fr 1fr;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 1200px;
}

.box {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
}

.box.d {
    grid-area: 2 / 3 / 4 / 3;
}
.box.b {
    grid-area: 1 / 2 / 3 / 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="box a">Content Here</div>
  <div class="box b">Content Here</div>
  <div class="box c">Content Here</div>
  <div class="box d">Content Here</div>
  <div class="box e">Content Here</div>
  <div class="box f">Content Here</div>
<div>
```

But it sometimes depends on the content of the columns.